# What is wrong with my boolinq .orderBy?

Tags: c++, linq, stl, c++11

So I try next compilable code:

```
#include <math.h> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>   
#include "boolinq.h"

float dtSqrt(float x)
{
    return sqrtf(x);
}

/// Returns the distance between two points.
///  @param[in]     v1  A point. [(x, y, z)]
///  @param[in]     v2  A point. [(x, y, z)]
/// @return The distance between the two points.
inline float dtVdist(const float* v1, const float* v2)
{
    const float dx = v2[0] - v1[0];
    const float dy = v2[1] - v1[1];
    const float dz = v2[2] - v1[2];
    return dtSqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz);
}

int main () {
    float target[] = {1,2,3};

    float floats1[] = {1.321f,2.123f,3.333f};
    float floats2[] = {1.011f,2.234f,3.555f};
    float floats3[] = {1.9f,2.9f,3.9f};
    float floats4[] = {1,2,3};
    float floats5[] = {1,2,3.123f};

    std::vector<const float *> floatsVector;
    floatsVector.push_back(floats1);
    floatsVector.push_back(floats2);
    floatsVector.push_back(floats3);
    floatsVector.push_back(floats4);
    floatsVector.push_back(floats5);

    //stl way
    //std::sort(floatsVector.begin(), floatsVector.end(),  [&](const float* pointA, const float* pointB) -> bool{
    //  auto distA =  dtVdist(pointA, target);
    //  auto distB =  dtVdist(pointB, target);
    //  return distA < distB;
    //});
    // auto stl_point = floatsVector.front();

    try {
        auto point = boolinq::from( floatsVector )
            .orderBy([&](const float* point) -> float{
                auto dist =  dtVdist(point, target);
                return dist;
        })
            .reverse()
            .toVector()
            .front();

        std::cout << point[0] << " " << point[1] << " " << point[2] << ";" << std::endl;

    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

having [boolinq header](https://code.google.com/p/boolinq/) this programm compiles quite fast. Yet it fails ***uncachably!*** at runtime with some inner vector assertion error:

[image]

problem is:

```
 boolinq::from( floatsVector )
                .orderBy([&](const float* point) -> float{
                    auto dist =  dtVdist(point, target);
                    return dist;
            }).toVector();
```

is empty vector.

uncommenting stl code makes programm work as expected!

futher more simple point reordering makes it work as expected:

```
float floats1[] = {1,2,3};
float floats2[] = {1,2,3.123f};
float floats3[] = {1.321f,2.123f,3.333f};
float floats4[] = {1.011f,2.234f,3.555f};
float floats5[] = {1.9f,2.9f,3.9f};
```

A really strange bug...

btw next code:

```
#include <math.h> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>   
#include "boolinq/boolinq.h"

struct Point {
    float X;
    float Y;
    float Z;
    Point() : X(0), Y(0), Z(0) {}
    Point(float X, float Y, float Z) : X(X), Y(Y), Z(Z) {}
};

float dtSqrt(float x)
{
    return sqrtf(x);
}

inline float dtVdist(const float* v1, const float* v2)
{
    const float dx = v2[0] - v1[0];
    const float dy = v2[1] - v1[1];
    const float dz = v2[2] - v1[2];
    return dtSqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz);
}

inline float dtVSqrDist(const Point & v1, const Point & v2)
{
    const float dx = v2.X - v1.X;
    const float dy = v2.Y - v1.Y;
    const float dz = v2.Z - v1.Z;
    return dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz;
}

int main () {
    auto target = Point(1,2,3);
    auto pointA = Point(1,-2,3);
    auto pointB = Point(1,2,3);

    std::vector<Point> pointsVector;
    pointsVector.push_back(pointA);
    pointsVector.push_back(pointB);

    //stl way
    std::sort(pointsVector.begin(), pointsVector.end(),
        [&](const Point & pointA, const Point & pointB) -> bool{
            auto distA =  dtVSqrDist(pointA, target);
            auto distB =  dtVSqrDist(pointB, target);
            return distA < distB;
    });
    std::reverse(pointsVector.begin(), pointsVector.end());
    auto stl_point = pointsVector.front();

    std::cout << "stl point: " << stl_point.X << " " << stl_point.Y << " " << stl_point.Z << ";" << std::endl;

    //try {

    auto points = boolinq::from( pointsVector )
        .orderBy([&](const Point & point) -> float{
            auto dist =  dtVSqrDist(point, target);
            return dist;
    })
        .reverse()
        .toVector();

    auto point = points.empty() ? Point() : points.front();

    std::cout << "boolinq point: " << point.X << " " << point.Y << " " << point.Z << ";" << std::endl;

    //} catch (std::exception &e) {
    //  std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    //}
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Produces:

```
stl point: 1 -2 3;
boolinq point: 0 0 0;
```

What is wrong with my code? It looks alike orderBy examples thay provide on [main boolinq page](https://code.google.com/p/boolinq/)...?

Comment: @NicolBolas with the library he linked to: https://code.google.com/p/boolinq/

Comment: btw: in VS2012, VS2012 with november CTP same results....

Answer (score 2):

Apparently boolinq does not support .orderBy().reverse() - which is somewhat worrying, granted.  If you sort by the negative distance (without reverse), it works.

To me this looks like boolinq isn't ready for serious use.

Comment: yet reverse (with no orderBy) works... it is really sad..  because with linq use vector<complexType> use would get really much simpler...

Comment: consider that orderBy isn't a critical feature - you can always save to a temp. vector and simply sort.  Since that's what happens behind the scenes anyhow, it's not such a bad idea - and then you can a different, non-booLinq C++ range implementation (such as boost ranges) that's more robust but happens not to implement orderby