# Opensource C++ LINQ library with dot notation, orderBy and firstOrDefault?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, linq

I search for a VS2010 compatable C++ linq library with C# LINQ dot sintax. meaning something like: `from(...).where(...).orderBy.firstOrDefault();`

I googled and found this [so answer LINQ libraries collection/mess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232222/is-there-a-linq-library-for-c):

- [Rx Extensions cpplinq](https://rx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/332fa75ecdb1#Ix/CPP/src/cpplinq/linq_where.hpp) has no `orderBy`
- [Boolinq](https://code.google.com/p/boolinq/source/browse/) has [strange orderBy behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422449/what-is-wrong-with-my-boolinq-orderby) and no first out of the box
- [cppex (cppextensions)](https://bitbucket.org/ronag/cppextras/src/master/linq/linq.hpp) code I tested (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422449/what-is-wrong-with-my-boolinq-orderby)) crashed vs2010 compiler (C1001)
- [linqxx](https://github.com/hjiang/linqxx) has no `orderBy`

Others I found not using dot notation.. btw [pfultz2/Linq](https://github.com/pfultz2/Linq) seems to provide orderBy and first yet its SQL like LINQ sintax and [Limitations](https://github.com/pfultz2/Linq#limitations) make it something I am not looking for=(

So Is ther any opensource C++ LINQ library with dot notation, orderBy and firstOrDefault?

Comment: The term "stable" sort [has a special meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability), which I don't think you mean here - you should rephrase.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne:  rephrased.

Comment: If there is none that meets all your needs. It is time to start hacking. You might either enhance one of the strongest of them, or start your own.

Comment: Actually [pfultz2/Linq](https://github.com/pfultz2/Linq) does support `order_by` and `first` as extension methods: `auto q = people | linq::order_by([](person p){ return p.name; }) | linq::first;`. If you want to fix the compiler errors for msvc, that would be great. Or you can always change to a better compiler.

Comment: My library **linq-cpp** has pretty much all of the .NET LINQ functions available: https://github.com/timothy-shields/linq-cpp/tree/v1 (link is for version 1 of the project) - Version 2 (the current HEAD of master branch) has loads of improvements but isn't finished yet. At the very least, check out version 1. :) - If you're interested in this kind of project, contact me! I'm looking for collaborators to help me really polish it off and make it the best C++ LINQ library available.

Comment: Forgot to mention - **linq-cpp** of course has dot notation, OrderBy, and FirstOrDefault - I wouldn't be mentioning it otherwise. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I will not give you the reply you want, but it will be a reply anyway :-)

LINQ is thought for C# mainly. I think your use case should be for translating C# code into C++, but I think that the effective way in C++ is to use [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference.html).

Boost.Range reuses the c++ standard library in a way that is easy to do query on data:

1. You can use adaptors for containers with left to right notation using `operator |`. They are evaluated lazily, just as in LINQ.
2. You can perform operations such as `std::min, std::max, std::all_of, std::any_of, std::none_of` in the adapted ranges.

An example I wrote the other day is how to reverse words in a string.
The solution was something like this:

```
using string_range = boost::iterator_range<std::string::const_iterator>;

struct submatch_to_string_range {
    using result_type = string_range;

    template <class T>
    string_range operator()(T const & s) const {
        return string_range(s.first, s.second);

    }
};

string sentence = "This is a sentence";

auto words_query = sentence |
                ba::tokenized(R"((\w+))") |
                ba::transformed(submatch_to_string_range{}) |
                ba::reversed;         


vector<string_range> words(words_query.begin(), words_query.end());

for (auto const & w : words) 
cout << words << endl;
```

I highly recommend you to base your queries upon this library, since this is going to be supported for a very long time and I think it will be the future.
You can do same style of queries.

It would be nice if this library could be extended with things like `| max` and `| to_vector` to avoid naming the vector directly and copying, but I think that as a query language, right now, it's more than acceptable.